# Django add to many to many field working without save

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, orm

What's the difference between

```
group.reportedBy.add(request.user)
group.save()
```

**AND**

```
group.reportedBy.add(request.user)
```

It gets saved to the DB even without me doing .save()

Comment: If you do not update a field of the `group` (not a `ManyToManyField` because these are implemented with a hidden table), then saving the group makes no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not update a field of the `group` (not a `ManyToManyField` because these are implemented with a hidden table), then saving the group makes no sense.

Django implements a `ManyToManyField` with a [*junction table* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity). This means that it constructs a extra table with two `ForeignKey`s: one to the model where you define the `ManyToManyField`, and one to the target of that field.

In case you want to add a link to the `request.user` it thus will *not* update the table behind the `Group` model. It will simply insert an extra entry in the junction table where it populates the `ForeignKey` to the `Group` model with the primary key of `group`, and the `ForeignKey` to the user model with the primary key of `request.user`.

This thus means that adding, removing, clearing, etc. the many-to-many relation will *not* make changes to the `Group` object, and hence it should not be saved. By saving it, you make a useless query.

Comment: Yes, I've seen the junction tables. Okay only when there are object changes apart from the manytomany fields a save query makes sense, thank you!